# Is it true that $\forall x,y\exists z(P(z)\wedge P(x)\wedge P(y))\sim\forall x\exists z(P(z)\wedge P(x))\wedge\forall y\exists z(P(z)\wedge P(y))$?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am trying to prove a theorem that uses similar equivalence and I think that the expressions above are in fact equivalent. Note, that $P(\cdot)$ is just a logical expression.

I explain it to myself in the following fashion: suppose $\forall x, y \exists z(P(z) \wedge P(x) \wedge P(y))$ is true. Then, no matter what $y$ we have, $P(z) \wedge P(x)$ for all $x$. Similarly, we have $P(z) \wedge P(y)$ for all $y$, no matter what $x$. So, we conclude that $\forall x \exists z(P(z) \wedge P(x)) \wedge \forall y \exists z(P(z) \wedge P(y))$.

My question is: are the expressions equivalent? If yes, is my way to explain it rigorous enough for a beginner's course in analysis or there should be more formal/rigorous way to prove it?

$\textbf{Edit:}$ I learned that you can swap the order of the universal and existential quantifiers. So:

$$
\forall x \forall y \exists z(P(z) \wedge P(x) \wedge P(y)) \sim \exists z \forall x \forall y(P(z) \wedge P(x) \wedge P(y))
$$

Also, the universal quantifier distributes over conjunction, so:
$$
\exists z \forall x,y (P(z) \wedge P(x) \wedge P(y)) \sim \exists z \left[ \forall x,y P(z) \wedge \forall x,y P(x) \wedge \forall x,y P(y) \right]
$$

But how do I proceed formally to complete the proof? I am clearly missing some useful properties of expressions involving quantifiers.

$\textbf{Edit 2:}$ I'd like to correct my mistake. I actually want to show that:
$$
\forall x,y\exists z(P(z)\wedge Q(x)\wedge R(y))\sim\forall x\exists z(P(z)\wedge Q(x))\wedge\forall y\exists z(P(z)\wedge R(y))
$$
I don't think this changes the logic I used in the beginning of the question.

Comment: The expressions are equivalent, and while your logic is correct, you have shown an *implication*. You did not show *equivalence* because you did not show that $\forall x\exists z(P(z)\wedge P(x))\wedge\forall y\exists z(P(z)\wedge P(y)) \Rightarrow \forall x,y\exists x\left(P(z) \wedge P(x) \wedge P(y)\right)$. Also, you should write this out more formally if you are turning it in as coursework.

Comment: The two expressions are equivalent because both of them are absurdly complicated ways of writing $\forall x\,P(x)$.

Comment: @stonebrakermatt please see my edit, I am still confused as to how to show this more formally.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I should have pointed out, my mistake is that all the 3 expressions are not the same, i.e. instead of writing $P(x), P(y), P(z)$ I should have written $P(x), Q(y), R(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is still way too complicated. Looking at the second expression, $\forall x\exists z(P(z)\wedge Q(x))\wedge\forall y\exists z(P(z)\wedge R(y))$.

Note that if for all $x$ there exists a $z$ such that $P(z)\wedge Q(x)$, that means: for all $x$ there exists a $z$ such that $P(z)$ and $Q(x)$ are true, or $Q(x)$ is true for all $x$ and $P(z)$ is true for at least one $z$. Your question would become different if $P,Q$ and $R$ would be dependent on multiple variables, for instance $P(x,z),Q(y,z)$ etc.

This should give you the insight that the second expression is exactly the same as the first expression, just written down a little more difficult.